# Proof of contractibility of a tree in May's "A concise Course in Algebraic Topology"

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Here is an excerpt from the book (pp. 35-36 in the online version):

[image]

[image]

I do not understand the need for making arbitrary choices for $T(v)$ and $T(v')$ -  there is a unique path from $v$ to $v_0$ (up to a reparameterization), so we can always take $T(v)$ to be the image of that path, and as $T(v')$ it seems natural to  choose $T(v) \cup j$.

I don't see at all what role the union $T(v) \cup T(v') \cup j$ plays in the proof. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define $T(v)$ to be the image of the path from $v$ to $v_0$, either it is the case that $T(v') = T(v) \cup j$, or else it is the case that $T(v) = T(v') \cup j$. In this case, yes: we could replace $T(v) \cup T(v') \cup j$ by $T(v) \cup j$, or by $T(v') \cup j$, or by $T(v) \cup T(v')$. We would have to prove that this property holds for paths in a tree, so the more concrete approach also takes more work.

It is a matter of taste whether arbitrary choices are to be avoided. Your point of view seems to be "we can write down a specific object that $T(v)$ can be, so why bother speaking so generally". A competing point of view is that all we *need* is for $T(v)$ to be a finite subtree of $T$ containing $v$ and $v_0$, so we might as well just say that it is a finite subtree of $T$ containing $v$ and $v_0$ - and assume nothing else. From that point of view, what we *need* the image of $h$ to be is a simply connected set containing $T(v)$, $T(v')$, and $j$, so we might as well define it to be $T(v) \cup T(v') \cup j$.

Comment: Thank you for the second part - I was worried I was missing some important point there! Regarding your remark about the relative positions of $v$ and $v'$: if $v'$ is closer to $v_0$ than $v$, isn't it the case that $a(v') \subset T(v)$ and then the choice $T(v) \cup j$ still works? So that $T(v') = T(v) \cup j$ works regardless of the relative position of $v$ and $v'$ with respect to $v_0$?

Comment: In the case that $T(v), T(v')$ are the images of paths, then yes; I suppose I should adjust my answer to reflect that. In the general case, no; $T(v')$ could include some extra edges that are not part of $T(v)$, and $a(v')$ could perversely walk down those edges (and then walk back).